# Basis for column space of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

A problem on my homework asks us to find a basis for the column space of the following matrix:

\begin{bmatrix}3&-9&6\\-2&6&-4\\1&-3&2\end{bmatrix}

The answer I got is {(3, -2, 1)}

I checked this in two different column space calculators online and one got the same answer as me, but another site had an answer with two vectors in the basis. So I just want to make sure that I got the correct answer? Is the column space one-dimensional or two-dimensional?

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is correct; so would be any nonzero multiple of it (so it surprises me that the online calculators got "the same answer").

Perhaps your third online attempt involved a typo -- even a single missing minus-sign could  change everything -- or it involved a site that didn't do computations correctly. Can you point us to the site that gave the wrong answer?

Comment: Yes, it's http://www.gregthatcher.com/Mathematics/ColumnSpaceCalculator.aspx

I checked for a typo but there wasn't one -- in his version he reduces just to row-echelon form (not all the way to reduced row-echelon form) and used the pivots in that matrix to find the column space

Comment: I just used that site and it produced the correct answer. Sigh.